# Changing an Image resource

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

When I'm clicking on a button, I want to change an Image view to different picture, to wait 3 seconds, and to change it again to another picture (without clicking again).

> 1 click -> change picture -> wait 3 seconds -> change picture.

This is my code:

```
northLight.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_and_yellow);

try {
     TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(3000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {}

northLight.setImageResource(R.drawable.green);
```

While I'm running the program, when I'm actually clicking the button, the program ignores the first `setImage` and changes it straight to the second `setImage` (to the green).

How can I solve this?

Comment: use handler for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using a Handler to wait and change the image. When your button gets clicked, change your image and run the handler with a delay of 3 seconds.

```
//Call this method when your button is clicked
public void changeImage() {
    northLight.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_and_yellow);

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            northLight.setImageResource(R.drawable.green);
        }
    }, 3000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use handler for it,

```
northLight.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_and_yellow);
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
 // Actions to do after 3 seconds
         northLight.setImageResource(R.drawable.green);
}
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
new CountDownTimer(3000,1000){
  @Override
  public void onTick(long l) {
    northLight.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_and_yellow);
  }
  @Override
  public void onFinish() {
    northLight.setImageResource(R.drawable.green);
  }
}.start();
```